# Percentage from age data in a column

Tags: r

I am using R for a project for University. I imported a csv file and created a df. Everything was going smoothly until I had to gather the percentages of age groups in the "Age" column. There are 3,000 rows of information in my df. How do I only sample information from rows 50-200 to find the percentages of people ages 15-20, 21-25, 26-30, and 31-35?

Comment: Hello, can you post an example showing the structure of your data frame? It will be easier to help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: If your question is "how to sample the rows 50 to 200, then, assuming your df is called df in the environment:
`df[50:200, ]` in base R, 
or using the package dplyr, `df %>% slice(50:200)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can sample the row indices like so (this will only sample one row): `df[sample(20:500, 1),]`. If you need to sample with replacement then `sample` has a `replace` argument.

Comment: use `dplyr::between` to filter people between certain age.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating another df which only takes information from rows 50-200 using the slice function e.g  `my_data %>% slice(1:6)` would give rows 1-6 I believe. Incase you didnt know, this function exists in tidyverse, which you can call using `library(tidyverse)`. For filtering by particular age groups, you can again use the tidyverse filter function, e.g `my_data %>% filter`.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to sample, better than slice specific rows you can use the function `sample_n`